# Django - AttributeError

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I created my custom User model. While doing migrations, I get an AtrributeError

```
from django.db import models
from time import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUsermanager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, is_anonymous, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, user_type, image_path):
        now = timezone.now()

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The gives emial must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            is_anonymous=is_anonymous,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            email=email,
            username=username,
            home_address=home_address,
            user_type=user_type,
            image_path=image_path,
            created_time=now,
            last_login=now
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_a_admin(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):
        return self._create_user(1, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, 0, image_path)

    def create_a_nonanonymous_patient(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):
        return self._create_user(0, first_name, last_name, email, username, 1, password, home_address, 1, image_path)

    def create_an_anonymous_patient(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):
        return self._create_user(1, first_name, last_name, email, username, 1, password, home_address, 1, image_path)

    def create_a_nonanonymous_helper(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):
        return self._create_user(0, first_name, last_name, email, username, 2, password, home_address, 2, image_path)

    def create_an_anonymous_helper(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):
        return self._create_user(1, first_name, last_name, email, username, 2, password, home_address, 2, image_path)

    def create_a_prof(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password, home_address, image_path):
        return self._create_user(0, first_name, last_name, email, username, 3, password, home_address, 3, image_path)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_anonymous = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user_type = models.IntegerField(1)
    image_path = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    created_time = models.TimeField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'home_address', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type']

    objects = CustomUsermanager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/users/%s/' % urlquote(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

and the exception is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 22, in  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 355, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_arg
>   v
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 327, in execute
>       self.check()
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\checks.py", line 77, in check_user_mod
>   el
>       if isinstance(cls().is_anonymous, MethodType):
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 68, in **init**
>       super(AbstractBaseUser, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 557, in **init**
>       _setattr(self, field.attname, val)
>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Can anybody point out where is wrong?

Comment: What migration are you running? [mcve]

Comment: @HåkenLid I don't know what you mean. I just do "python manage.py makemigrations"

Comment: I'm puzzled why you have a model field called `is_anonymous`. That might be what's causing this problem, since that's supposed to be a read only attribute in `AbstractBaseUser` that always returns `False`. Try removing that field and run makemigrations.

Comment: I can confirm @HåkenLid's findings. To view the properties and methods of the AbstractBaseUser class, see here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py

Comment: @noahandthewhale, Thank you! That is really a coincidence!

Answer (score 0):

```
user = self.models(
        is_anonymous=is_anonymous,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
        email=email,
        username=username,
        home_address=home_address,
        user_type=user_type,
        image_path=image_path,
        created_time=now,
        last_login=now
    )
```

replace models